Trouble Scraping Image URLs from a Webpage
I'm attempting to scrape image URLs from a webpage using BeautifulSoup and requests in Python. The webpage I'm targeting is the Minecraft wiki page for blocks. However, I'm encountering an "IndentationError: unexpected indent" at line 35, which is for img_tag in soup.find_all('img', class_='mw-file-element'):. I'm not sure what's causing this issue. Can anyone help me identify and resolve the problem?
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re

# URL of the website containing the block names and images
url = 'https://minecraft.wiki/w/Block'

# Send a GET request to the URL
response = requests.get(url)

# Parse the HTML content of the page
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

# Find all elements containing block names and images
blocks = []
for li in soup.find_all('li'):
    name_element = li.find('a', class_='mw-redirect')
    
    if name_element:
        name = name_element.text.strip()
        url = 'https://minecraft.wiki/w/' + re.sub(r'\s+', '_', name)
    
        blocks.append({'name': name, 'url': url})

for block in blocks:
    print(block['name'])
    print(block['url'])

images = []
for block in blocks:
    block_url = block['url']
    response = requests.get(block_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    
        for i in soup.find_all('img'):
                image_element = i.find('img', class_='mw-file-element')
                if image_element:
                    srcset = image_element.get('srcset', '')
                    original_image_url = re.search(r'^(.+\.png)', srcset)

                    if original_image_url:
                        image_url = 'https://minecraft.wiki' + original_image_url.group(1)
                        images.append({'image:' : image_url})

for image in images:
     print(image['image'])


Yo have an extra indent in the second for loop:for i in soup.find_all('img'): put it at the level of the previous line (the soup= ..  line) and it will solve that issue.

Try something like this:
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re
import time

url = 'https://minecraft.wiki/w/Block'

response = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

blocks = []
for li in soup.find_all('li'):
    name_element = li.find('a', class_='mw-redirect')
    
    if name_element:
        name = name_element.text.strip()
        url = 'https://minecraft.wiki/w/' + re.sub(r'\s+', '_', name)
    
        blocks.append({'name': name, 'url': url})

images = []

for block in blocks:
    response = requests.get(block['url'])
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

    for img in soup.select("img.mw-file-element"):
        # Get src attribute from <img> tag.
        src = img.get("src")
        # Strip off any parameters.
        src = re.sub("\?.*$", "", src)
        url = "https://minecraft.wiki"+src
        print(url)
        images.append({'image:' : url})

    # Pause.
    time.sleep(10)

I've corrected the syntax error in the second loop. I also took a look at how you were extracting the image URLs and have made some suggested changes. I hope that I correctly understood what you are trying to achieve.
I added in a pause in the second loop, just so that your traffic on the site is low.
I'd suggest that you consider another data structure (like a set) for storing the images because there's likely to be some duplication.
Same output looks like this:
https://minecraft.wiki/images/thumb/Oak_Button_%28S%29_JE4.png/150px-Oak_Button_%28S%29_JE4.png
https://minecraft.wiki/images/thumb/Spruce_Button_JE4_BE2.png/150px-Spruce_Button_JE4_BE2.png
https://minecraft.wiki/images/thumb/Birch_Button_JE3_BE2.png/150px-Birch_Button_JE3_BE2.png
https://minecraft.wiki/images/thumb/Jungle_Button_JE3_BE2.png/150px-Jungle_Button_JE3_BE2.png
https://minecraft.wiki/images/thumb/Acacia_Button_JE3_BE2.png/150px-Acacia_Button_JE3_BE2.png
https://minecraft.wiki/images/thumb/Dark_Oak_Button_JE3_BE2.png/150px-Dark_Oak_Button_JE3_BE2.png
https://minecraft.wiki/images/thumb/Mangrove_Button_JE1_BE1.png/150px-Mangrove_Button_JE1_BE1.png
https://minecraft.wiki/images/thumb/Cherry_Button_JE2.png/150px-Cherry_Button_JE2.png
https://minecraft.wiki/images/thumb/Bamboo_Button_JE3.png/150px-Bamboo_Button_JE3.png
https://minecraft.wiki/images/thumb/Crimson_Button_JE1_BE1.png/150px-Crimson_Button_JE1_BE1.png

